# Display image from response

Tags: java, image, jsp, spring-mvc, httpresponse

I have write the image into `httpresponse`, I defined the `contentType` for the image.

```
response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

What is the syntax to display this image in jsp?

Comment: what is the content type you get at your client and what is the error ?

Comment: Did you try an `<img src="url to your stream">` tag?

Comment: @JigarJoshi - my content type in image/png, Not getting any error I jus want to know the syntax to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `base64` encoding for this. For this you'll need to encode it as base64 on the server side and embed that on client side as -

```
<img src="data:png;base64,base64_encoded_image_here">
```

Of course, png can be replaced with appropriate mime_type. The downside it that the image will be part of the HTML content. But there won't be a separate HTTP request for this image.